# How to update the SF URL in workbench?

Tags: community

Oct 9 SF are enforcing My Domains which means our URL gets updated. any one give me a steer o how to access out W/B to update the URL for our org? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to update anything within workbench.

Workbench, like any other [connected app](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_overview.htm&type=5), works by having you log into your org and authorizing [OAuth](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_authenticate.htm&type=5) to access your org. You can see this on your user record in your org under `OAuth Connected Apps`

When you click on `Login with Salesforce` from workbench, you're presented with a login screen. You can continue to login with your `username + password` through `login.salesforce.com` as before mydomain was enabled.

If you've disabled logins through login.salesforce.com or have a setup that requires SSO through your domain, you can type in your domain on the prompt to login by clicking on `use custom domain`.

[image]

In terms of what to consider when enabling mydomain, there's a [My Domain Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_considerations.htm&type=5). You'll notice it mentions what I say above as well:

> **Logging In with a My Domain**
>
> After you deploy a My Domain, your users
> can log in to your org with its My Domain URL.
>
> Alternatively, users can log in to your org after a My Domain is
> deployed using these methods:
>
> - https://login.salesforce.com, unless an admin prevents logins through
>   the My Domain policies options.
> - Your org’s instance URL, such as
>   https://InstanceName.salesforce.com/, unless an admin prevents logins
>   through the My Domain policies options.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add to the above information, if you are signed into a browser already to a SF Org, the option to sign in using a Custom Domain may not be available.

For instance if your browser is signed into Trailhead and you want to use Workbench with a different Org, this option will not be available to you. Use a different persona or an incognito tab.